# MongoDB query slow in join using $ne to look for not empty arrays

Tags: mongodb, join, indexing

I'm new to Mongo and I have a slow query when using $ne in a match pipeline (to get the records that match only and not all the ones where the array is empty)

The query is as follow:

```
 db.EN.aggregate([
 {
     $lookup: {
  from: 'csv_import',
  let: {pn:'$ICECAT-interface.Product.@Prod_id'},
  pipeline: [{
      $match: {
          $expr: {
              $eq: ["$$pn","$part_no"]
          }
      }
  }],
  as: 'part_number_info'
     }
 }, { $match: { part_number_info: { $ne: [] } } }
 ]).pretty();
```

When I remove the `{ $match: { part_number_info: { $ne: [] } } }` the query executes in 21 seconds, vs almost 2 hours when executed using the $ne clause.

There's an index already on ICECAT-interface.Product.@Prod_id, and here are the 2 collections structure sample:

csv_import:

```
{
  "_id": "ObjectId(\"6348339cc6e5c8ce0b7da5a4\")",
  "index": 23679,
  "product_id": 4019734,
  "part_no": "CP-HAR-EP-ADVANCED-REN-1Y",
  "vendor_standard": "Check Point"
}
```

EN:

```
[{
  "_id": "1414",
  "ICECAT-interface": {
    "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation": "https://data.icecat.biz/xsd/ICECAT-interface_response.xsd",
    "Product": {
      "@Code": "1",
      "@HighPic": "https://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/1414-HP.jpg",
      "@HighPicHeight": "400",
      "@HighPicSize": "43288",
      "@HighPicWidth": "400",
      "@ID": "1414",
      "@LowPic": "https://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/low/1414-HP.jpg",
      "@LowPicHeight": "200",
      "@LowPicSize": "17390",
      "@LowPicWidth": "200",
      "@Name": "C6614NE",
      "@IntName": "C6614NE",
      "@LocalName": "",
      "@Pic500x500": "https://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery_mediums/img_1414_medium_1480667779_072_2323.jpg",
      "@Pic500x500Height": "500",
      "@Pic500x500Size": "101045",
      "@Pic500x500Width": "500",
      "@Prod_id": "C6614NE",
```

**SOLUTION**

I did add an index on part_no field in csv_import and I changed the order of the query to be smaller to large (EN is 27GB and csv_import is a few MB)

Final query: (includes the suggestion made by nimrod serok

```
db.csv_import.aggregate([
 {
     $lookup: {
  from: 'EN',
  let: {pn:'$part_no'},
  pipeline: [{
      $match: {
          $expr: {
              $eq: ["$$pn","$ICECAT-interface.Product.@Prod_id"]
          }
      }
  }],
  as: 'part_number_info'
     }
 },{$match: {"part_number_info.0": {$exists: true}}}
 ])
```

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference in terms of performance or correctness, but I think your `$lookup` could use the "simpler" `localField`/`foreignField` syntax instead of the `let`/`pipeline` version since it's a direct single field match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option is to use:

```
{$match: {"part_number_info.0": {$exists: true}}}
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-6neQojdGoY)

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to see if it improves, I checked explain() and in both cases it does COLLSCAN, is there anything that can be done in terms of indexing here?

Comment: I added an index on part_no (in csv_import collection) and it improved a lot!

Comment: I also reverted the order of the join, I did small to large, cuz EN is about 27GB of data and csv_import is a few MB

Comment: Curious - what benefits does this change to the post-`$lookup` match have? In terms of performance and/or correctness

Comment: @user20042973, does your question regard the answer, or the comments on it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was asking about the answer. Genuinely curious in what ways the `$exists: true` predicate is better than `$ne: []` for post `$lookup` filtering.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals, but as far as I know (based of previous answers here), this is the best way to know  if an array contains items. I might be mistaken.